# Dynamic Text Position on Image

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

I have the above image, in which the size of the various aspects is covered and shown in form of letters; some of which are e, s, d; should be numbers which dynamically coming from the database.

I know how to achieve this through backend however I am not too sure about how can those digits be dynamically placed over the image.

Any help will be of gr8 help.

Comment: What do you mean from "dynamically"? Do you have database connection problem? or you mean dynamic x,y of place on image?

Comment: I would use an SVG image. It would be clean that way but would obviously also require you to make the image into an SVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use an SVG, you need to put the `img` in a `div` that has `position: relative` and then you can append the numbers with `top` and `left` css attributes where they need to go

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/pk9bfzcw/

```
<div style='position: relative;' id='imageContainer'>
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9vQS.jpg'/>
</div>

<script>
var letter = {
  label: '5',
  top: 80,
  left: 5
}

var letter_elem = document.createElement('span');
letter_elem.style.top = letter.top + '%';
letter_elem.style.left = letter.left + '%';
letter_elem.innerHTML = letter.label;
letter_elem.className = 'number';

document.getElementById('imageContainer').appendChild(letter_elem);
</script>

<style>
.number {

    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    left: -1000px;
    font-size: 28px;
    min-width: 32px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;

}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well however not too sure if it will work for multiple values and if I can pass dynamic data in the `label`

Comment: Where are you getting your values from? Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it using css

```
<div class="col-xs-6 form-group media">
    <div class="outerWrapper">
        <img title="blockMeasurement" class="center-block" src="/resources/images/image.png" />        
                <span class="badge">{{dynamicdata}}</span>
         </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.media img+span.badge{
    position: absolute;
    right:-5px; // change this to the position you want over the image
    top:0px;//change this appropriately
    height:2rem;
    width:2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
}
.outerWrapper{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 150px;

}
```

The css basically places the  on the  tag and you can position it wherevr you want on the image.

Answer (score 0):

## Use svg

animate it with javascript if needed.

```css
svg {
  width: 250px;
}
#shape1 {
  stroke-width: 5;
}
#shape2 {
  stroke-width: 5;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 210 150">
  <g id="shape1">
    <rect x="30" y="10" width="40" height="80" fill="none" stroke="black" />
    <line x1="10" x2="90" y1="40" y2="40" stroke="#aa3eee" />
    <text x="110" y="50" transform="rotate(-90, 110, 50)" font-size="25px">30</text>
    <line x1="30" x2="30" y1="130" y2="90" stroke="red" />
    <line x1="70" x2="70" y1="130" y2="90" stroke="red" />
    <text x="0" y="120" font-size="25">30</text>
  </g>
  <g id="shape2">
    <rect x="130" y="40" width="70" height="70" fill="none" stroke="black" />
    <line x1="130" x2="130" y1="130" y2="110" stroke="red"/>
    <line x1="200" x2="200" y1="130" y2="110" stroke="red"/>
    <text x="150" y="132" font-size="25">30</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```